# Selenium. How to navigate element who's href contains a certain string?

Tags: selenium

I have several `<a`elements. But only one of them has a substring "long" as a value for the attribute `href`

```
<a class="ggg" href= "very_lpng string" > name1 </a>
<a class="ggg" href= "verylong string" > name2 </a>   // The one that I need
<a class="ggg" href= "very ling string" > name3 </a>
<a class="ggg" href= "very ng string" > name4 </a>

...................
```

I want to click the link who's href has substring "long" in it.
How can I do this?

**PS:   `driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("long")).click();` is not helping because it is looking for the substring "long" NOT WITHIN THE `href`**