# How to click a link whose href has a certain substring in Selenium?

Tags: java, selenium

The following is a bunch of links `<a elements.` ***ONLY one*** of them has a substring "long" as a value for the attribute href

```
<a class="c1" href= "very_lpng string" > name1 </a>
<a class="g2" href= "verylong string" > name2 </a>   // The one that I need
<a class="g4" href= "very ling string" > name3 </a>
<a class="g5g" href= "very ng string" > name4 </a>

...................
```

I need to click the link whose `href` has substring "long" in it. How can I do this?

PS: `driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("long")).click();` // b/c it chooses by the name

Comment: Why are you creating another question on this? You asked the same question three hours ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19055327/selenium-how-to-navigate-element-whos-href-contains-a-certain-string

Comment: I am sorry, i wanted to delete the previous question, and open a new one so that i would be able to expres myself more clearly...this question deserves attention, because it is not as easy as it seems

Comment: but apparently i cannot delete the previous question. There is already an answer (not correct) to the previous question

Comment: For something like this, it's probably best to use xpath, although I'm not 100% sure my xpath is correct:

    `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//@href[contains(text(), 'long'.)]).click();`

Comment: Thank you I tried this method. it is not working unfortunately

Comment: where does this "driver" come from?

Answer (score 109, accepted):

> I need to click the link whose href has substring "long" in it. How can I do this?

With the beauty of CSS selectors.

your statement would be...

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[href*='long']")).click();
```

This means, in english,

> Find me any 'a' elements, that have the `href` attribute, and that attribute `contains` 'long'

You can find a useful article about formulating your own selectors for automation effectively, as well as a list of all the other equality operators. `contains`, `starts with`, etc... You can find that at: http://ddavison.io/css/2014/02/18/effective-css-selectors.html

Answer (score 6):

use `driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("long")).click();`

Comment: Thank You for the answer. However, this would work only if I was looking for the substring within the name of the link. This does not work if one is looking for a substring within the `href`

Comment: The link text is the text that is displayed. This answer won't work, since the only link texts given are 'name1','name2','name3','name4'.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this:

```
//first get all the <a> elements
List<WebElement> linkList=driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));

//now traverse over the list and check
for(int i=0 ; i<linkList.size() ; i++)
{
    if(linkList.get(i).getAttribute("href").contains("long"))
    {
        linkList.get(i).click();
        break;
    }
}
```

in this what we r doing is first we are finding all the `<a>` tags and storing them in a `list.After` that we are iterating the list one by one to find `<a>` tag whose href attribute contains long string. And then we click on that particular `<a>` tag and comes out of the loop.

Comment: in this what we r doing is first we are finding all the <a> tags and storing them in a list.After that we are iterating the list one by one to find <a> tag whose href attribute contains long string. And then we click on that particular <a> tag and comes out of the loop.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please consider adding some explanation to your answer, rather than just code alone. Our goal here is to educate people so that they understand the answer and can apply it in other situations. If you comment your code and add an explanation, you will make your answer more helpful not just to the person who asked the question this time, but to anyone in the future who may be having the same problem.

Answer (score 3):

With the help of xpath locator also, you can achieve the same.

Your statement would be:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//a[contains(@href,'long')]")).click();
```

And for clicking all the links contains long in the URL, you can use:-

```
List<WebElement> linksList = driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//a[contains(@href,'long')]"));

for (WebElement webElement : linksList){
         webElement.click();
}
```