# Trying to locate an href that contains text

Tags: python, selenium

I am very new to coding - We are using Selenium with python scripting.

Please find the attached screen shot for the HMTL of my page.

The actual web page is a table that has "x" for all the user accounts.

I am trying to locate the href attribute that contains a user account that I pass as variable.(In the below example I am trying to click on the link that has "expample@exampleemail.com" )

Can someone please help me locating the element.

Thanks!

Comment: You forgot to attach the screenshot.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can find the element by [`xpath`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/locating-elements.html#locating-elements):

```
text = "example@example.com"  
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[contains(@href, "%s")]' % text)
```

Answer (score 2):

I've answered a similar question [here...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19058637/selenium-how-to-click-a-link-whos-href-has-a-certain-substring/19059180#19059180)

In your case, just translate the java to python.

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a[href*='example@example.com']")
```

Comment: Getting the following error when trying the above code (<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement object at 0x1038f80d0>)

Comment: Oops.. Sorry for the comment above.. It worked.. Thank you very much

Comment: @user3570279 great to hear!  hand an upvote and accept the answer if it solved your issue `:)`

Comment: Tried to Upvote but system says that I require 15 reputations to up vote so was not able to do that.

Comment: @sircapsalot since your answer helped too and mine was accepted, here's your +1 :)