# How to click a link whose href contains some string in Selenium Python?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

I want to click on a link who has "930" in his url for this [site](http://www.auchandrive.fr/)

```
<div id="liste_drives">
    <ul>
    <li class="">
        <span class="left">
        02 -
        <a href="http://www.tt.com/d/n/p/st-985">tt</a>
        <p class="a"> </p>
        </span>
        <a class="entre"  href="/d/m/St-985/">i enter here</a>  
    </li>
    <li class="">
        <span class="left">
        03 -
        <a href="http://www.tt.com/d/n/p/ee-930">tt</a>
        <p class="a"> </p>
        </span>
        <a class="entre"  href="/d/m/ee-930/">i enter here</a>
    </li>
</div>
```

i read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19058637/how-to-click-a-link-whose-href-has-a-certain-substring-in-selenium)

and i try this :

```
id = "930"
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('"a[href*=%s]" %id').click()
```

but i can't click on url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `%id` part should be outside of the string for the string formatting to properly work:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a[href*=%s]" % id)
```

Note that this assumes that `id` has alphanumeric characters only. If not, you need to enclose the value into the quotes:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('a[href*="%s"]' % id)
```