# Node.js Selenium can't find element. No such element error

Tags: node.js, selenium

So i have this element:

```
<a href="/my_sites"></a>
```

and i just can't find it, tried

```
driver.findElement(webdriver.By.partialLinkText('my_sites')).click();
```

but that just throws no such element error

Answer (score 0):

I believe selecting by partial link text searches the visible text (the text in between the opening and closing a tag) rather than the href. Since you have no text within the a tag, it is not finding it. You would have to find using xpath something like "//a[contains(href, 'my_sites')]"

Answer (score 0):

For selenium link text is what you find between the HTML brackets, for example:

```
<a href="/my_sites">LinkText</a>
```

You can try to select via CSS selector:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[href*='my_sites']")).click();
```

Check this link for more info:

[How to click a link whose href has a certain substring in Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19058637/how-to-click-a-link-whose-href-has-a-certain-substring-in-selenium)

Comment: driver.findElement(By.css("a[href*='my_sites']")).click();      i changed cssSelector to css  otherwise i was getting error but still it says unable to locate element.. maybe there is somekind of timing? i mean maybe it looks for element before the page is even loaded?